# Laravel's confusing internal use of `tap()` helper

Tags: laravel

Was going through Laravel commits and saw this:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/de811ea7f7dc7ecfc686b25fba48e4b0dac473e6

If you can't be bothered following the link, here's a screenshot:
[image: some weird shit]

The earlier version seems infinitely more readable (and probably executes faster too). Am I missing something that `tap()` provides?

I get that there is a "Laravel way" to do things that isn't necessarily the obvious way and that it is an opinionated framework, but stuff like this really confuses me.

So I guess the crux of the question is: Is this a Laravel quirk or is there a reason or magic functionality going on behind the scenes that explains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a Laravel quirk, but it seems the tide is turning back the other direction!

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37363/commits/d14f09b72bd2f722a9fb0af35b4f477ebaec7b80

Pedantic little things, but I'm ever so slightly happier

Answer (score -1):

In my option, the main purpose of this function is to help the coder write a single block code, avoid declaring intermediate variables.

[The author's view on this function](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/tap-tap-tap-1fc6fc1f93a6)